# Opendaylight Running Docker Container

Tags: docker, container

I am running a container in Opendaylight using the command

docker run -d -p 6633:6633 -p 8181:8181 -p 8101:8101 --name=opendaylight glefevre/opendaylight

After running the command I get an error

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint opendaylight (276de8a95cc9080d56851e5833ed58be3066c57cad4e68d01ceacaa7ed6a904e): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8181: bind: address already in use.

Comment: "address already in use"  means you already have something active on port 8181. Probably another docker instance? Kill that 1st if that is the case

Comment: Can you tell the command

Comment: I am not able to solve the issue

Comment: But you are able to search the internet yourself: [LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=docker+stop)

Comment: yes I am, but still the issue is same